# C++ Reference Variables (reference variables, pointer variables)

Tags: c++, pointers, variables, reference

Can someone please explain why we get the output we see in the following source code?

```cpp
#include <iostream> 

int main()   {  
   int x{ 10 };
   int &rx{ x };
   rx = 123; 
   std::cout << x << " " << rx << std::endl;  
}
```

**Output**

```
123 123
```

Why is the output `123 123` and not `10 123`?

Also: what is the difference between `int x {10};` vs `int x = 10;`?

Comment: Because that's what references are? What is your understanding of what reference is, and how it works?

Comment: Check references in c++ here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/references-in-c/

Answer (score 2):

`rx` is a [*reference*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) (alias) to `x`. Reading a value from `rx` will read the value from `x` instead. Assigning a value to `rx` will assign the value to `x` instead.  `rx` is not an actual variable with storage, it has no value of its own.

As for [initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization):

`int x {10};` is using [Direct Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) syntax:

> Initializes an object from explicit set of constructor arguments.

`int x = 10;` is using [Copy Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) syntax:

> Initializes an object from another object.

Comment: However, when I try to compile 
int x{10}; into c++ and try to output, I get an error. Do you know why?
cout<< x << endl;

Comment: @tall_call_9129 You need to be more specific. What does the error actually say? And which compiler and C++ version are you compiling with?

Comment: It is telling me to insert a semi colon between x and the bracket {. In other words, int x;{10}; which does not make any sense as I still cannot run my code. I am currently on a macbook and using VScode

Comment: @tall_call_9129 VScode is an IDE/editor, not a compiler. What *compiler* are you using? What *version* of C++ are you targetting? I'm guessing it is not C++11 or later. If `int x{10};` won't compile, then you will have to use `int x(10);` or `int x = 10;` instead.

Comment: thanks so much! yes when I do int x(10); it does work! Yeah it seems like my version of c++ is not 11 or later. Would you know how I could implement int* p{new int[5] {999,3,5,8,1}}; into my version of C++? I have tried to do int *p (new int A[5](999,3,5,8,1)); however that does not work

Comment: @tall_call_9129 you can't initialize an array of values using parenthesis until C++20. And being able to initialize a dynamic array with values directly in a `new[]` expression was introduced in C++11.

Comment: Yeah I figured! How could I know which version I have? The only way I could initialize an array with the new[] is by doing the following:

main() {
int *p; 
p = new int[5];
int[0] = 10;
int [1] = 20;
int[2] = 30;
int[3] = 40;
int[4] = 50;

*p=6; 
std::cout << x << " ," << *p << endl;
delete[] p;
return;
}

Do you know another way of writing this for the version I am currently using?

Comment: @tall_call_9129 sorry, that is the only way to do it pre-C++11. BTW `int[index]` is wrong, you meant `p[index]` instead. As for the C++ version, you still haven't answered my earlier question yet - "*[VSCode is not a compiler] What compiler are you using?*". Refer to your compiler's documentation to see which C++ version it defaults to, and how to specify a different version. Most compilers support a `--std=X` or equivalent flag, where `X` is the desired C++ version.

Comment: I am unsure how I can check the version I have (I even tried to verify online) haha do you know how I can confirm the version I have?

Comment: @tall_call_9129 VSCode does not have a C++ compiler of its own. You had to have installed a compiler for it. So, which compiler did you actually install? Gcc? Clang? Msvc? Mingw? Etc

Answer (score 0):

`&rx=x` means that `rx` is a reference, ie another name, for `x`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).